# Visual Studio Professional not showing Web projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional and I cannot open a Web project in there.  Before installing Visual Studio 2010 Pro, I had Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer Express installed.  Would this be the cause of the problem?  Do I need to uninstall both and reinstall VS 2010 Pro to get Web projects to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue, I had to click `Tools->Import and Export Settings`.  Then, select `Reset all settings`.  Before doing this, I had uninstalled Web Developer Express, but it should work without doing that.